# How to get Extension Attribute in a model in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, model, extension-attributes, interface

I have added an extension attribute by creating extension_attributes.xml file in etc. Its content is:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
   <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
      <attribute code="custom_field" type="string" />
   </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now when I try to get extension attribute in model I use following code:

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $address = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface');
 echo $address->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomField();
```

But the problem is `$address->getExtensionAttributes()` return NULL. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As also written [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171132/magento-2-losing-data-with-extension-attributes-in-bundle-options-collection/171763#171763) (different question but same answer):

> The documentation for extension attributes is not quite clear on
>   what's the right way to use them and it seems like each entity type
>   does it in a slightly different way.
>
> That being said, from my experience you have to create plugins to
>   populate the extension attributes, and also to save them. It is not
>   done automatically.
>
> Take a look at `Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Plugin\OrderGet` and
>   `Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Plugin\OrderSave` for an example.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at it and then see what happens.

Comment: any update on this?