# How do you get values from Quote_address table Magento 2

Tags: quote, shipping-address, customer-address

I have added new column in **Quote_address** table but I am not able to get the value when i do the following steps;

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
 $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

Is there anything wrong in this code ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, orders are stored in `sales_order` (and `sales_order_address`) in contrast to `sales_quote` (and `sales_quote_address`). It looks to me as if your code uses orders, and you can't get the quote address this way.

However, you should read about extension attributes, as this is the way new fields should be added in Magento 2.

I think this question & answer might help: [How to get Extension Attribute in a model in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172013/how-to-get-extension-attribute-in-a-model-in-magento-2)

Comment: I followed this and this didn't get the value either